# How can extension start/stop debug sessions without user interaction?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Newcomer to extension development in vscode here.

I would like to make an extension that automatically start/stop based on folder events. 
I searched in the doc, but I still lack experience to actually understand if it's even possible to begin with.

I've found https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/api-debugging
but the example is not *starting* a debug. It's creating a new adapter.

So, is it even possible using extension API to start/stop debug sessions *without* user interaction ?
And if yes, how ?

Comment: Does that make sense? Debugging means to identify errors and fix them. How can this be done without user intervention? And no, I believe there's no way to do that from extension code.

Comment: This is a plugin to help reload compound debug where you have 3+ simultaneous debug session. That _would_ make sense.